# The content of a polynomial $f\in F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Given a UFD $R$, and $F = \mathrm{Frac}(R)$, we can define the content of a polynomial $f\in F[X]$, $f =  a_nX^n + \cdots + a_1X + a_0$, by $c(f) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal P} p^{v_p(f)}$, where $v_p(f) = \min_{0 \leq i \leq n} v_p(a_i)$ are the valuations and $\mathcal P$ is the set of all primes in $R$.

> I've been told that if $c(f) = 1$, then $f \in R[X]$, but I'm unsure how to show this.

I'm trying to show that the coefficients $a_i$ of the polynomial are in $R$. The condition $c(f)=1$ tells me that no prime $p$ divides all the coefficients of $f$, but I don't know how this helps?

Intuitively I gather that no prime $p$ appears in any of the denominators of $a_i \in \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ because $v_p(f) = 0 $ for all primes $p$, and so the coefficients must be in $R$. But this is hardly rigorous?

Comment: So to calculate $c(f)$ you select one $a_i$ (how?)  and calculate the above product? This means $c(f)$ is associated with $a_i$!

Comment: Your definition of the content is not rigourous: why should a specific coefficient $a_i$ and only this coefficient play a role?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I meant for $ 0 \leq i \leq n $

Comment: @Bernard Sorry I have fixed it now. $V_p(f) = \min_{0 \leq i \leq n} V_p(a_i)$

Comment: @theman Write $a_i=r_i/s_i$ with $r_i,s_i\in R$ and $\gcd(r_i,s_i)=1$. Then $v_p(a_i)\ge 0$ iff $p\nmid s_i$. On the other hand, $c(f)=1$ iff $v_p(f)=0$ for all $p$. Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 1):

$c(f)=1$ means $v_p(f)=1$ for all primes $p$, and this implies $v_p(a_i)\ge 0$ for all $p$ and all $i$. So all the $a_i$ are in $R$.

In fact, $c(f)$ is the $\gcd$ of the $a_i$.